# running pycharm Python Code in command line headless

Tags: python, selenium

```
running pycharm Python Code in command line headless  

I have code in following  folder structure
```

#Main_Folder
   ## -Folder1
   ###--first.py
   ###--second.py (imports methods from first.py) also has its own class Second
   ###--main.py (calls both first.py and second.py to run sequentially) import statement in main-> 
                       from Folder1.second import Second
    ##-Folder2
    ###--file.xlsx (imported in first.py in a method)

```
I want to run my entire script headless in command prompt

I tried following 

1. At folder location main_folder ran following command on prompt
pytest main_folder\folder1\main.py --headless
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'

2. At folder location main_folder ran following command on prompt
pytest folder1\main.py --headless
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'

Can anyone help please how to achieve the headless execution of my code
```

Comment: I am new to Python automation. i dont know why people are giving dislikes here. Seems no one wants to help

Comment: What do you mean by "headless"?

Comment: @novacoil I created the scripts through pycharm and when I run it there it works fine but now I have to run it in linux environment with headless browser. I am facing hard time in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to have at least part of your code that exhibits the issue.

From the error message `No module named 'folder1'`, I suppose that you are doing something wrong with your `import` statements.

PyCharm has a tendency to mess with your PYTHONPATH, especially when running `pytest`.

Check that your imports are coherent and that directories that contain python code [are python packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) (i.e contains an empty `__init__.py` file).